# integrating several sql server databases into a 'data ware house'

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I intend to create a 'data ware house' that integrates several sql server 2008 databases. This integration solution will only have a life time of 12 months or so. Hence, I do not want to spend lots of time creating a star schema etc. Still the 'data ware house' database will contain some conforming dimensions. Is it worth replicating the source databases in the 'data ware house' or shall I just create some cross database views + stored procedures + conformed dimensions in the 'data ware house'? Any feedback would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it depends what you're planning to do with the warehouse, usually warehouses created to look for historical data and run analytics on them to get the trends and problems that occured historically and to get these analysis out of it, it runs big queries which does lot of aggregation on lots of data. If you just create some across database views than it will work on your OLTP data and it might degrade the performance of your main running system.

Pro's for DataWarehouse:
1. you can view historical data without affecting main system
2. you can generate trends out of it with out degrading main system performance
3. Since all historical data is in warehouse, you can lighten your main DB which will increase performance on the main app
4. you can merge all db's into one

cons for Datawarehouse
1. It take some hit on your main db when you copying the records to the warehouse and if there are frequent updates on the historical records, then you have to keep up the warehouse with that
2. It is not supposed to be used for real time queries

Comment: Thanks, makes sense. Would you recommend transactional replication of the publisher data?

Comment: it again depends what you're trying to achieve here, transactional replication for high availability systems where you have replicated db's and if one goes down you can switch it to other, they aren't best suited for warehouse purposes, but again it depends on your use case